# Why isn't express rendering index.html from the build folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-fullstack

I have the following which should render my front end

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

I have set the NODE_ENV to production just to double-check that the build/index.html is what's being served, but what is actually rendered when I run `npm start` is
[localhost:5000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtO4A.png)

Why isn't it rendering my front and what have I done wrong, I've spent almost a week trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong,  any help would be appreciated

Comment: For starters, `path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build')` should probably be `path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')`.  Same with `path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')`.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that before with

`if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
  });
}`
and I get the same result

Comment: In the Chrome debugger, go to the Network tab, click on the index.html file and on the right side, find the response headers to see the `content-type` and see what it is.  If the browser is rendering as text instead of HTML, it's probably because the content-type is wrong.

Comment: Not sure why but I deleted the following and it worked 
`app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  next();
})`

Thanks for taking the time to respond